# Unable to restyle activityChooserView

Tags: android

I'n my theme I'm trying to restyle the easy share action on the action bar to remove the border around the icons. I found

```
<item name="activityChooserViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActivityChooserView</item>
```

In the holo theme but I'm unable to use it in my theme; in fact, there's no activityChooserViewStyle in R.attr but only in R.attr in ActionbarCompat. So the item is present in the holo them but it's not exposed in R.attrs.
Is there a solution to this? Should I use ActionbarCompat even if I'm only supporting api level 14+?